# SQL Server 2000: Get person with most sales in each month. (Trouble replacing rank function for SS 2000)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, rank

I am trying to get a list of salespeople and how many months they have sold the most in terms of value. I have working query, but I did not realize until now, that I wont be able to use the `rank` function since this site uses a sql server 2000.

Here is my current query

```
select top 5 name, count(*) as amount
from
(
     select e.first_name + ' ' + e.last_name name,
     RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), oe.entry_date, 105), 7) as date, sum(oe.totalPrice) price,
            rank() over(partition by RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), oe.entry_date, 105), 7) 
                order by sum(oe.totalPrice) desc) as ranking
     FROM order_entry oe
     INNER JOIN employees e ON oe.sales_rep_emp_number = e.employee_number
     group by e.first_name + ' ' + e.last_name, RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), oe.entry_date, 105), 7)
) temp
where ranking = 1
group by name
order by count(*) desc
```

I need to replace that inner query with something that does not rely on the `rank` function. I found a few ways to "reproduce" the effects of this function, but they involved making a temp table with an identity column, which is used as the rank table. However, I have several rankings (one for each month), so that will not work. Furthermore, I thought there might be another way to achieve this without the `rank` function.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go back to first principles.  The following query gets the top 5 employee numbers:

```
select top 5 sales_rep_emp_number, COUNT(*) as numMonths
from (select yr, mon, MAX(TotalPrice) as maxTotalPrice
      from (select year(oe.entry_date) as yr, month(oe.entry_date) as mon, oe.sales_rep_emp_number,
                   SUM(totalPrice) as totalPrice
            from order_entry oe
            group by year(oe.entry_date), month(oe.entry_date), oe.sales_rep_emp_number
           ) yme
      group by yr, mon
     ) ym join
     (select year(oe.entry_date) as yr, month(oe.entry_date) as mon, oe.sales_rep_emp_number,
             SUM(totalPrice) as totalPrice
      from order_entry oe
      group by year(oe.entry_date), month(oe.entry_date), oe.sales_rep_emp_number
     ) yme
     on ym.yr = yme.yr and
        ym.mon = yme.mon and
        ym.maxTotalPrice = ye.totalPrice
group by sales_rep_emp_number
order by 2 desc
```

This has the same "flaw" as the `rank()` -- where multiple employees can be counted as top in a given month if they have the same sales.

I've left outer the part where you join in the additional employee information.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I guess I fell too in love with the function and couldn't seem the simpler (or as  you put it first principle-based) solution. Have a good day!